# Can I use Bowden hotend instead of Wade for a direct extrusion?

Tags: extruder, bowden, wade

I am planning to buy 4 hotends (e3d clones I assume), but I am wondering if **the Bowden (long distance) be able to be used as Wade (direct extruder)?**. When the pneumatic fitting is removed there is a very similar filament drive to the throat/heat-brak and the collar size is same as wade.
As per attached pictures, I think that could be possible.
[image: front view]

[image: hotend]

Comment: You can use any of them, however the adaptor  will be different to make it fit on your printer. I´m using the J-head on direct drive by removing the pneumatic connector; the distance fromt top to filament hole is close to 4mm, but does not  affect the feeding. If the cylinder hasn't the pneumatic connector is possible to print a cap to mount the connector and make it remote drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of them, however the adaptor will be different to make it fit on your printer. I´m using the J-head on direct drive by removing the pneumatic connector; the distance from top to filament hole is close to 4mm, but does not affect the feeding. If the cylinder hasn't the pneumatic connector is possible to print a cap to mount the connector and make it remote drive